# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in website/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 39

Tags: php, wordpress

Issue is with an unmodified version of wordpress 4.5.2 and results in having to do automatic updates not working.

I have tried disabling all plugins, downloading 4.5.2 and updating wordpress manually (replacing all files) following the guide here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress

I've tried doing some backtracing and var_dumping but haven't been able to find a solution - any ideas/solutions?

Comment: I am facing same problem. I am on managed WP hosting so I can not modify any of wp-admin or wp-include files due to file permission. I believe there is an issue with DB entries. Did you find any solutions?